# Python Pandas: Convert Date to Text e.g. 2018-08 --> August

Tags: python, pandas

Forgive me if the format of this is incorrect, it's my first post.

I'm using Python with Pandas and I have a column named "Month" with the values underneath such as "2018-08" for August 2018, obviously. I'm trying to change the "2018-08" values to "Aug" or August".

What I tried so far is:

df = df.rename(index={"2018-08":"Aug"})

Also tried '' instead of "" in case it made a difference.

I ran df.dtypes and I noticed columns "Month" is object if this makes any difference.

Can anyone lend a hand as of how to convert the numerical values to string?

Apologies again if this looks like a mess!

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` routines like so:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-08', "%Y-%m").strftime('%b') # 'Aug'
```

or

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-08', "%Y-%m").strftime('%B') # 'August'
```